# Counting number of columns in Excel using talend

Tags: excel, counter, talend

I would like to know how I can count the number of columns of an excel sheet using Talend

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count no. of columns in the Excel file then please follow the below instructions.

1. Use tfileinputExcel component.
2. Add some basic instruction in the component with limit 1 but important is "Put one name in Schema 'excel_header' (You can use any name) and change its type to 'Dynamic' ". It will fetch the full row from the excel file.
3. Now Use second component 'tjavaRow'. Link your excel component through the 'main' row to tjavarow component.
4. Syn your schema in tjavarow component and put below mentioned code.

System.out.println("Counter ::: "+input_row.excel_heade.getColumnCount());

5. Now your job will count columns for you.

Note: You can store this counter value in any context variable and can use it.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Amine...Actually, I have used an R script to do so and run it in tsystem component. the flow you are proposing seems very interesting, however, the datatype dynamic does not seem to appear in my version of Talend Studio. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Dynamic columns are supported only in License version of Talend.

Answer (score 0):

```
tFileInputExcel (just read 1 row i.e. column headers record) ----> tFileOutputDelimited 


tFileInputDelimited (read the file created above) --> tNormalize --> tFilterRow_1 (filter null & blank rows) --> tJava_1
```

In tJava_1 component, you can get the number of rows by using *(String)globalMap.get("tFilterRow_1_NB_LINE_OK")*.

This number of rows actually represent your number of columns in excel.